# Why does my website allow body content on GET requests?

Tags: rest-api

Temporary question: I always thought that we first need to send a GET request to get a nonce and by sending back the nonce on the header of our POST request, WordPress allows the body of a POST request to be read (to let us send data to WordPress). But today I was playing around with its rest API that I realized we can send anything in our requests body even with GET requests and that's accessible with get_params() function inside WordPress. Isn't it a vulnerability? How can I forbid GET requests with body?

Sorry for my poor English.